# It should be possible to navigate and edit the filter of NatTables using the keyboard only (no mouse required)?

Tags: java, eclipse, nattable

It should be possible to register or bind a keyboard shortcut to filter rows using any command?

If Yes, I want to bind a keys in such a way that it should.

- the command should access the filter of the same column that holds the active cell (if for some reason the filter of that column is not accessible

  - not sure whether possible
  - then the first filter column from left should be accessed that is accessible; same if no cell is currently active); if a filter term is already available, it should be retained and selected (same than when mouse clicking on the filter nowadays)

i.  keyboard shortcut SHIFT+CTRL+F should be assigned to the command.

ii.  Within the filter fields, it should be possible to use TAB to move one filter field to the right and allow direct editing (preserving value if present), and SHIFT+TAB to move one filter field to the left (if reaching leftmost column, SHIFT+TAB should jump to rightmost column filter; if reaching rightmost column, TAB should jump to leftmost column filter).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported. You would need to extend the editors somehow to add such a support.